# core data vs. strong database

Tags: iphone, sql-server, database, core-data

I'm writing an iphone application that will be executing many queries over a database containing lots of data including geography and geometry types, but has a very simple schema. database obviously will be located on a server

here are my questions:
1. can core-data hold large databases
2. does core-data support geography and geometry types like spatial features in sql server and oracle databases?
3. what is the best practice and the recommended database when it comes to iphone applications

thank you

Answer (score 2):

> can core-data hold large databases

When it comes to databases, people have very different ideas of what "large" means. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717068/643383) nicely covers the limitations of Core Data; essentially, the limitations of Core Data depend on the underlying data store. On iOS, Core Data uses SQLite for data storage.

> does core-data support geography and geometry types like spatial
>   features in sql server and oracle databases?

If you're thinking of Core Data as a database, you're really doing it wrong. Core Data is an object persistence manager. It doesn't have any spatial features; on the other hand, you can write whatever code you want in the objects you store in Core Data.

> what is the best practice and the recommended database when it comes
>   to iphone applications

Naturally, that depends. If you want a traditional database, there's SQLite. If you have a large graph of objects to manage, use Core Data. If connectivity won't be an issue, web services connecting to a server-side database can be the way to go.

Comment: I think of core-data in objective-c as the entity-framework of C#, as such they are an object representation of the relational database, in entity framework has a built-in support for the spatial data types, my question in that regard was if core-data has a built-in support for those data types, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, after working with online databases as well as Core Data, online databases with REST API are your best bet. I haven't seen the option to use special types like spatial features, Apple only gives you their basic types.